# objective-c Xcode black screen displays when going to next view controller

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i am using parse to do logins for my user. when the user presses the login button it displays a black screen instead of the user profile.
my code is :

```
UIStoryboardSegue *loginView = [[ViewController_userprofile alloc]init];
[self presentModalViewController:loginView animated:YES];
```

Comment: You are passing `UIStoryboardSegue` to a method which takes a `ViewController` as parameter. Also, Parse is shutting down, by the way.

Comment: yeah its is, not till next year which is lucky so can get the coursework done before then. thank you i will give that a go.